# Flow to Update Entire List Once a Day

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

Okay, I ignorantly stumbled into creating a flow that updates a the Date column for a specific User every 10 min.

Recurrence: 10 min.
Update Item: Site: List: Id: Date: utcNow()
Terminate: Succeeded

The above works. My assumption is if I change the Recurrence to 24 hrs. this action will take place every 24 hrs, yes?

Also, how to I edit the above to my it impact every record on the list, rather than just only mine?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update all the list items, you will need to use the **get items** action and  **Apply to each**. Inside the **Apply to each** control, adding the update list item action to do so.

Example:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Apply-to-each-update-to-all-items-in-the-list/td-p/446536

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Best-way-to-update-SharePoint-List-every-day-and-few-other/td-p/147198